# How do I search for the value "city"?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I'm trying to query through a somewhat simple collection with the following structure:

```
{
   "name":[
      {
         "something":"",
         "somethingelse":[
            {
               "name":"John",
               "city":"NY"
            }
]}]}
```

I have tried to search the value "city" with the dot notation but no success.

Comment: This should work, `db.collection.find({"name.somethingelse.city": "NY"})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by reading this [mongoDB doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/), I see that to access array nested document you need to specify the index of the element instead of using ".".

For example with this object:

```
{
     "name":"bob",
     "info":[
         {"birth":"10/01/1986"},
         {"eyeColor":"blue"},
         {"salary":2000}
     ] 
}
```

I want to access the "birth" property, I will do something like this:

```
db.inventory.find({'info.0':"birth"})
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the data and store it in an object say ob

```
ob= {
   "name":[
      {
         "something":"",
         "somethingelse":[
            {
               "name":"John",
               "city":"NY"
            }
]}]}
```

now you can do `ob["name"][0]["somethingelse"][0]["city"]`